# How to get started writing a compositing WM?

Tags: linux, x11, clutter, compositing

I would like to write a basic hardware-accelerated window manager, so I've been looking for some documentation on how to get started, but I've only managed to find [this tutorial](http://wingolog.org/archives/2008/07/26/so-you-want-to-build-a-compositor), which uses an outdated version of Clutter and won't build with any version currently available. Are there any other good resources for how to do this, or alternatively, a really bare-bones compositing WM to look at the source of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two parts in your question: 1) How to write WM 2) how to write composite manager

Some links to help understand part two (in addition to xcompmgr source):

- http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/x11-composite-tutorial/ (Uses Qt, but very generic and low level)
- https://github.com/gustavosbarreto/compmgr
- http://projects.mini-dweeb.org/projects/unagi

Window manager, "part one":

- I have simple ~100 loc wm in JavaScript: https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11/blob/master/examples/windowmanager/wm.js
- another minimalist wm (in C), good to start as a reference: https://code.google.com/p/winmalist/
- most important keyword: `SubstructureRedirect` event mask. A bit of documentation [here](http://menehune.opt.wfu.edu/Kokua/Irix_6.5.21_doc_cd/usr/share/Insight/library/SGI_bookshelves/SGI_Developer/books/XLib_PG/sgi_html/ch16.html#S1-1002-16-2)

Answer (score 4):

The original demo compositing manager was [xcompmgr](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xcompmgr/), which I'd recommend for understanding the underlying X extensions.

If you're using OpenGL to do your hardware-accelerated rendering, you'll need to read up on the `EXT_texture_from_pixmap` extension to avoid copying window contents through userspace. That extension allows you to use hardware-accelerated blits for those copies instead.

You'll probably also be interested in the specification for [_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s06.html), to allow tear-free rendering synchronized to vertical retrace.

Answer (score 0):

You could try qtile it is very customizable with a python config (which also makes it extremely easy to get started with) you can pick between wayland and x11 and despite being written in python it's extremely fast