# How to apply a graphical effect on graphical output on the fly under linux?

Tags: linux, graphics, linux-device-driver, x11, compiz

I need to apply a bitmap effect on the screen image before it's displayed on screen. This must be done in real time. Ideally, this should work with all graphical output, including games. User must be able to use the computer as normal.

Can you advise me what is the best way to do this under linux? Can it be done in x11? Or display driver needs to be modified?

Note: this is a repost of the question where I asked the same thing under windows (I gave up): [How to apply an effect on screen image in Windows on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161244/how-to-apply-an-effect-on-screen-image-in-windows-on-the-fly)

Thanks!

Comment: If your CPU is decent and your graphic card is fairly powerful and supports all the recent stuff, you might be able to do it in much the same way compositing window managers work. You need to be reasonably well versed in X11 compositing. Start from studying the compiz window manager, or perhaps one of the more simple and accessible compositing managers e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260667/how-to-get-started-writing-a-compositing-wm). I have never done anything like that so I cannot be more specific

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I wonder if it would be simpler to use the GPU to downsample the screen image and upsample it again rather than blurring?